# How do I access variables from a broadcast receiver?

Tags: java, android, variables

This is probably all in Java mechanics that I don't know, but here's my problem:

I have an SMS receiver that spits out two variables, the sender and the message body. I'm trying to access them from a separate service. I have a toast message in my SMS receiver (as shown in the code) and it shows the message fine, but when I try to toast that same thing from the service, the message is nothing. So the SMS receiver is receiving the message correctly.

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public String senderNum;
public String message;

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    try {
        if (bundle != null) {
            final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

            for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
                SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);

                senderNum = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                String msg = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
                message = msg;

                Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: "+ senderNum + "; message: " + msg);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);
    }

    Intent i = new Intent(context, ChatHeadService.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startService(i);

    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, 
                                 "senderNum: "+ senderNum + ", message: " + message, duration);
    toast.show();
}
}
```

I am trying to access the variable using:

```
SmsReceiver r = new SmsReciever();
message = r.message;
sender = r.senderNum;
```

Comment: try to pass value of senderNum and message to ChatHeadService intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here i am specifying another way to access the value in **ChatHeadService**. You can change the code for invoking the **Service** by like this in **broadcastReceiver** class

```
 Intent i = new Intent(context, ChatHeadService.class);
 i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 i.putExtra("num",senderNum);
 i.putExtra("msg",msg);
 context.startService(i);
```

In **ChatHeadService**  you can retrive it as using the following code:

```
   Intent intent=getIntent();
   String message = intent.getStringExtra("msg");
   String senderInfo= intent.getStringExtra("num");
   Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, 
                             "senderNum: "+ senderInfo + ", message: " + message, duration).show();
```

Comment: I didn't know you can pass variables through intents :P thanks

Comment: Actually this is the common way to pass the values to another activity...try to use it...all the best...